# kolla-ansible SSL certificate expired

Tags: openstack, ssl-certificate-errors, kolla-ansible

My ssl certificate has expired in my openstack deployment and I can't login in and several services do not work well because of it.
How can I remediate to this? I tried to find a way to disable the verification but I didn't find. Then I tried to disable TLS on my globals.yml then deploy over, but it complains about some services still using TLS.
How can I workaround this problem to be able to install a new certificate?

Regards

Comment: where does it get time info?

Comment: If you are talking about NTP (chrony), it comes from a firewall.